# network issue-apple remote desktop 3

Tags: networking

I have a Comcast SMC Business cable router. I need to be able to manage this router from the internet via apple remote desktop. I know that the comcast smc router/modem is pretty stripped down. Is there any way to use apple remote desktop with this SMC router or will I need to use a 3 party router(dlink) to accomplish this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Apple Remote Desktop is built on VNC, so as long as you port-forward the VNC ports (5900 by default) through that router to the Mac that is running the management interface, you should be able to connect to the Mac.

There is a problem, though: your network design is sort of like chainsawing the limb you're standing on! Any reboot of the router will drop your VNC connection, and if you make a wrong move, you may not be able to get back in to fix it without trudging over to the physical location.

Point of order: have you seen serverfault.com? It might be a more appropriate place for a networking question like this one.